# Microsoft Graph Intune: How to get the "enrolled by" user data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

In Azure portal on a managed device detail page it shows two types of users,
The "Primary" user and the "Enrolled by" user. I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve the latter
using the Microsoft Graph API. What I've tried so far is pretty much every managed device related API.
The ones I mainly use are the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0 and [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)
I've also looked at pretty much all the beta variants of the related API documentation if and when they are available. My problem is that it seems like there is no way to retrieve this information.

Comment: Please check this property [deviceEnrollmentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-shared-deviceenrollmenttype?view=graph-rest-1.0) and see if it can help.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I think you are misunderstanding the question. Your answer has nothing to do with the identity of the user whom enrolled the device.

Comment: You can create a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that this could be implemented in the future.